# C# PInvoke and QWidget

Tags: c#, pinvoke, qwidget

I have an application that I am trying to automate on Windows. I need to find the location of a window that is running inside the application, and then automate a couple of mouse events on the application.

In a previous incarnation of the software that I am automating, I was able to search for child windows of the process which were named using the GetWindowText WinAPI function from C# (in combination with GetWindowTextLength).

The software manufacturers have now updated the software and updated the way that the child windows are drawn. Now each window lacks a caption, and has a class name of QWidget. I can no longer use my old strategy to find the child window location. I presume the use of QWidget means the windowing system uses the Qt framework.

Is there any way of pulling any data from the QWidget using PInvoke that I might be able to identify my windows with?

Comment: Have you checked what the window presents in the Spy++ tool?

Comment: Preet, yes. I've been snooping at the windows with Spy++. There is no further information there other than QWidget that I can use.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems here.  One is that you can't get "unshared" data from another process.  You can get at window data by pinvoking methods like `GetWindowLong`; but unless you know specific data about what QWidget does in that data (the other problem), there's not much you can do with the data.

Another problem is if you want to use most QT objects in a managed application (you can do this with C++/CLI and IJW) you need to initialize A QT Application object in your application...  I'm not sure how this would impact what you want to do.